# How to revalidate form validators with arrays inside using updateValueAndValidity

Tags: angular

"updateValueAndValidity" doesn't seem to work and reset the validators. I am listening for form value changes via:

```
this.myFormFixtures.valueChanges
                    .subscribe(formData => this.checkFixturesFormValidity(formData));
```

But the following function isn't setting the new validation:

```
checkFixturesFormValidity(formData)
    {
        console.log(formData);

        const control = <FormArray>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures'];

        for (let i = 0; i < control.length; i++) {

            const participantsControl = (<FormArray>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures']).at(i).get('participants') as FormArray;



                if ((((<any>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures']).at(i).controls['participants'].at(0).get('id').value) != null) || (((<any>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures']).at(i).controls['participants'].at(1).get('id').value) != null))
                {
                    (<any>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures']).at(i).controls['participants'].at(0).get('id').setValidators([Validators.required]);
                    (<any>this.myFormFixtures.controls['fixtures']).at(i).controls['participants'].at(1).get('id').setValidators([Validators.required]);


                }
                else
                {

                }


        }

        this.myFormFixtures.updateValueAndValidity();




    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to call it in a setTimeOut, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.myFormFixtures.updateValueAndValidity();
});
```